# jQuery: function on all elements but <a>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to run a function on the whole website but *not* on "a"s. Problem is, that the "a"s are inside "div"s, so selection like

```
$(':not(a)').myFunction();
```

does not work (since it is called on the parent-div). Sounds like a simple problem, I just don't seem to find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: do event.stopPropagation()

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scnq911c/1/

Comment: How far down does the a need to be for the function not to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now did it with unbinding the function on 'a's.

```
$('a').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tooltip').hide().addClass("hover");
...
```

and

```
$("body").on( "click", function() {
    ....
});

$("a").click(function() {
    $("body").off("click");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('body > *').not(':has("a")').myFunction();
```

You can replace the not() part with whatever you want to keep. The above should work for your example.

Comment: It is difficult to see if the answer works with your code as you have no other elements apart from the list of links. See jsfiddle here for a modified version of your html (which I added <h1> and <p> elements) https://jsfiddle.net/fionaredmond/9expnwbm/3/  When you run it you will see it fades out the <h1> and <p> but not the <a>'s like you are looking to achieve. This demonstrates the correct syntax to get .not() to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with the .not() function like so:

```
$('*').not('a').myFunction();
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/